# File encyrpted and passworded

Tags: windows, encryption, passwords

Files on my computer are encrypted. Programs that I found couldn't help me

File link: https://yadi.sk/d/wopusDRLuczoU

Virus total: https://www.virustotal.com/tr/file/e...is/1472630917/

Answer (score 2):

You could try and figure out what ransomware type virus has infected you. There are sites that can help with that. (eg. https://id-ransomware.malwarehunterteam.com/ ) (in your case I got back that you have AxCrypter ransomware, this is basically legitimate software that has been abused to encrypt your files.)

After you have done this you can try and search for tools to decrypt that specific malware. There is a chance the specific ransomware you have has been decrypted and tools are out there.

I used the search term decrypt ransomware 2016, depending on your type of ransomware you could specify your term more.

Some promising results:

https://noransom.kaspersky.com/

https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1114221

If you are lucky your ransomware has been solved already.

On a sidenote: if you know how you got infected try to learn from that. Try to think of a way to avoid being infected the same way. Most infections are because the victim unknowingly made a mistake. (opened email-attachment, didn't update system, ...)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Your files have been encrypted with the strongest possible cypher (using 256 bits encryption if I remember correctly) and nobody has ever been able to get them back.

Some people have paid the ransom, and some of them have been rumored to have actually received the decryption key, but lots of them just lost their money.

Quite some companies got caught here : just one employee opening the infected email, and everything that's in reach of the computer (i.e. shared folders on their servers etc.) gets encrypted in a matter of minutes.

Their only solution was a complete restoration from backups, so I hope you have some.

Last year, they were asking for a Western Union transfer, and this year they ask for a BitCoin payment on the Tor network, so good luck to find them.

The ones from last year have been arrested and I've heard they've apologized and sent the decryption keys for free... But the current ones are still running wild.

Last year's infection method was an executable (usually a .scr MS screensaver file) enclosed in a zip archive attached to the mail (and yet some unwary people still opened and ran them !) ; this year it's either javascripts or infected MS Word file (probably in a macro) attached to the mail.

Their common trait is no antivirus is able to detect them, so if you open them, boom, you're dead. They probably download the harmful part once running, after having silenced your antivirus.

The only known protection is to add a policy forbidding to run a program from a temporary folder (you need a professional version of Windows).

Plus the obvious one : never open such attachment...

Answer (score -2):

chances are, you've been infected by a CryptoLocker.

> CryptoLocker is a ransomware trojan virus that targets computers
>   running Microsoft Windows.

You can read more about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoLocker

There's little to no chance that you'll get those files back, unfortunately.

Comment: I want help to decrypt file

Comment: @AtayÖzcan There is no help without a password, that is the purpose of encryption.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)